# How to delete Entity from the database in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony6

I am using Symfony 6 and I created an entity using the command "php bin/console make:entity".
But it was a test, so now I want to remove completely the entity (PHP class + SQL table).

How can I delete it properly ?
Even if it was in production env.
Because I read that we shouldn't run "php bin/console d:s:u --force" in production env.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Updating, adding or removing entities can be performed like this:

1. Delete the entity file in `src/entity`.
2. Run the command `php bin/console doctrine:migrations:diff --allow-empty-diff`. (this will create the migration file in `/migrations`, look at this and you will see the sql commands)
3. Then run the command `php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate --allow-no-migration`. (this will run the migration file and update your db)
4. (optional) Clean up with `php bin/console cache:clear`.

I have added `--allow-empty-diff` and `--allow-no-migration` options, so if you are going to use a deployment script (for production), then these can be run all the time even if there are no differences or updates to your entities and no errors will be thrown.